# Using 'png' extension in Cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I need to generate an image (having remote path) with 'jpeg' extension as user profile picture in all browsers, so, I've a code line like below in 'routers.php' file:

```
    Router::extensions(['jpeg','gif']);
```

The corresponding part in the view looks like below:

```
echo $this->Html->image(['controller'=>'Images','action'=>'profilePicture'], ['alt' => $user['username'], 'data-lock-picture' => ['controller'=>'Images','action'=>'profilePicture'], '_ext' => 'jpeg']);
```

ImagesController.php

```
public function profilePicture() {
    $this->render('profilePicture', false);
    $this->Images->generateImage();
  }
```

ImagesTable.php

```
public function generateImage() {
    $src_path = 'https://.../photo/username.jpg';
    $image_string = file_get_contents($src_path); 
    if ($image_string !== FALSE) {
        $image_identifier = imagecreatefromstring($image_string); 
    imagejpeg($image_identifier);       
    }
  }
```

After adding 'png' extension in routes.php file:

```
    Router::extensions(['jpeg','gif','png']);
```

I'm getting an error message in Mozilla:

```
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://.../cakephp/images/profilePicture".
```

and there is no 'jpeg' image shown. But it works fine in Chrome.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: How should anyone be able to reproduce your problem with the given information? Just adding an extension will surely not trigger any problems in general, so please add more details so that people who don't know your application can reproduce the problem, otherwise it's unlikely that you'll get much help (see also **http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic**). Start with the including the _full_ stacktrace (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion)! that belongs to the error in case it is actually being triggered in CakePHP.

Comment: Also show/describe the proper context, ie show/highlight the code that actually triggers the error (ex. mark the code with line numbers that can be matched to the stacktrace), elaborate on your app/server environment (OS, used tools, etc.)!, and last but not least, please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version and tag your question accordingly - thanks! Often the problem solves itself when collecting these information.

Comment: @ndm: I've edited my question, could you please review it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was adding extensions in routers.php file. They already exist in "vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Validation/Validation.php" file.